# Transfer file in Secure Shell

Tags: shell, vim, ssh, file-transfer

I use Secure Shell as a Chrome extension (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/secure-shell/pnhechapfaindjhompbnflcldabbghjo?hl=da)

Now I have finished some programming and I need the file on my computer.

How can I transfer the file to my computer? Can I send it by email or something?

I have tried yanking all the lines in vim, but I still don't get it copied to my windows clipboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One entertaining (and moderately ridiculous) approach would be sprunge.

Run this on the remote machine:

```
cat myFile | curl -F 'sprunge=<-' http://sprunge.us
```

And then visit the URL it prints on your local machine. :D

Comment: A general comment: _don't do programming like this_. I assume the remote machine is where you're testing your software: so write it locally, and use `scp` or `rsync` or git or whatever to deploy and test. I can't think of anything more awful than writing code through a Chrome SSH extension :/

Comment: They actually enforce writing code in a shell via a browser extension? That's absurd :/

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I presume that you are using Windows OS and trying to download your file from a Linux like OS.

You use MobaXterm and it comes with a file transfer features.
http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net

On a CLI you can use "scp" to download and upload.

Another one is you can also use FileZilla using SFTP protocol

[image]